# Sum and shift values to nearest smaller date based on logical condition

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a data set `testdf` (dput below) which looks like this:

```
head(testdf)
#        Date ID Value InCalendar
#1 2014-01-01  A     0       TRUE
#2 2014-01-02  A    18       TRUE
#3 2014-01-03  A     0       TRUE
#4 2014-01-04  A    10      FALSE
#5 2014-01-05  A     0      FALSE
#6 2014-01-06  A     6       TRUE
# ...
```

Ultimately, I want to remove all rows where `testdf$InCalendar` is `FALSE`. But before removing those rows, I want to move those `Value` entries where `InCalendar` is `FALSE` to the closest date where `InCalendar` is `TRUE` AND where the Date is before that of the row(s) with `FALSE` entry in `InCalendar`.

The whole operations needs to be done by group of `ID`.

There is one valid assumption that the first entry in `InCalendar` is always `TRUE` and the `InCalendar` entries and `Date`s are the same across all `ID`s.

Note that `FALSE` entries in `InCalendar` may appear multiple times after each other, during weekdays or the weekend - there is no fixed pattern.

---

This does what I want but feels a clumsy and is pretty long:

```
library(dplyr)
testdf %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  group_by(InCalendar, grp = cumsum(c(0L, diff(InCalendar)) == 1L), add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Value = ifelse(InCalendar, Value, sum(Value))) %>%
  group_by(ID, grp) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(lead(InCalendar), Value, Value + lead(Value, default = 0))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(InCalendar) %>% 
  select(-grp)

#Source: local data frame [48 x 4]
#
#         Date ID Value InCalendar
#1  2014-01-01  A     0       TRUE
#2  2014-01-02  A    18       TRUE
#3  2014-01-03  A    10       TRUE
#4  2014-01-06  A     6       TRUE
#5  2014-01-07  A    10       TRUE
#6  2014-01-08  A     6       TRUE
#7  2014-01-09  A     9       TRUE
#8  2014-01-10  A    20       TRUE
#9  2014-01-14  A    10       TRUE
#10 2014-01-15  A     8       TRUE
#..        ... ..   ...        ...
```

---

My question is how the same result could be produced in a more succinct way using either base R or dplyr or data.table. I thought it might be a use case for data.table's roll join capabilities but I'm not very familiar with that, so would appreciate any suggestions.

---

Here's my test data `dput`:

```
testdf <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(16071, 16072, 16073, 16074, 
16075, 16076, 16077, 16078, 16079, 16080, 16081, 16082, 16083, 
16084, 16085, 16086, 16087, 16088, 16089, 16090, 16091, 16092, 
16093, 16094, 16095, 16071, 16072, 16073, 16074, 16075, 16076, 
16077, 16078, 16079, 16080, 16081, 16082, 16083, 16084, 16085, 
16086, 16087, 16088, 16089, 16090, 16091, 16092, 16093, 16094, 
16095, 16071, 16072, 16073, 16074, 16075, 16076, 16077, 16078, 
16079, 16080, 16081, 16082, 16083, 16084, 16085, 16086, 16087, 
16088, 16089, 16090, 16091, 16092, 16093, 16094, 16095), class = "Date"), 
    ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(0L, 18L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 0L, 13L, 
    0L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 12L, 
    0L, 476L, 48L, 470L, 0L, 166L, 222L, 220L, 219L, 32L, 454L, 
    0L, 231L, 195L, 205L, 193L, 36L, 474L, 0L, 258L, 239L, 214L, 
    203L, 29L, 438L, 0L, 98L, 14L, 96L, 0L, 36L, 58L, 46L, 38L, 
    5L, 90L, 0L, 51L, 49L, 54L, 50L, 7L, 108L, 0L, 55L, 45L, 
    48L, 35L, 6L, 86L), InCalendar = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-75L), .Names = c("Date", "ID", "Value", "InCalendar"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're making this much harder than it is:

```
dt = as.data.table(testdf)

dt[, Value := sum(Value), by = list(ID, cumsum(InCalendar))][(InCalendar)]
#         Date ID Value InCalendar
#1: 2014-01-01  A     0       TRUE
#2: 2014-01-02  A    18       TRUE
#3: 2014-01-03  A    10       TRUE
#4: 2014-01-06  A     6       TRUE
#5: 2014-01-07  A    10       TRUE
#...
```

Note, this will change the values in the original `dt`, if that's undesirable, use `copy`. And don't forget to sort by date before you start (your example data is already sorted). Also, since you say your `InCalendar` always starts with a `TRUE` within each group, if your data is sorted by `ID` and `Date`, as in the example, you don't actually need to group by `ID`.

Comment: Awesome, eddi. Thanks for opening my eyes - I was indeed overcomplicating things.. I guess that happens when you keep looking too long at your data. Very succinct solution! (+1) (Makes me feel slightly dumb now..)